# libgdx calculate overlapping percentage?

Tags: libgdx, overlap

I am using libgdx and I ned to calculate the overlapping percentage of 2 rects.

Actually it is the overlap of an Actor and a rectangle added to another Actor.

I want to highlight an actor if another actor is moved close to it so it is a proximity check.

And if there is 50% overlap I want to highlight. Then if the actor that is dragged close to the other is released with touch up i will let it slide close to the other actor.

So it is not simply collisioon detection, I need to know how much they collide.

Comment: This is a pure math question and if you search just a little, you find your answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99565/simplest-way-to-calculate-the-intersect-area-of-two-rectangles To calculate the percentage divide by the actors rectangle area.

Comment: i guess you need to implement the calculation which shouldn't be that hard. Just calculate the overlap if collision is true. Shouldn't be hard since you have the sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve it using Libgdx [Intersector](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) class. You will need to create two [Rectangles](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.html) and third one for result - all you need to do is to check the areas after intersecting them

```
    Actor a,b;

    ...

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(a.getX(), a.getY(), a.getWidth(), a.getHeight() );
    Rectangle s = new Rectangle(b.getX(), b.getY(), b.getWidth(), b.getHeight() );

    Rectangle result = new Rectangle();

    Intersector.intersectRectangles(r, s, result);

    if( result.area() >= 0.5f * r.area() )
    {
        //do something if result area is equal to 50% a Actor area or more...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.